# Why is Gravatar necessary for profile pic , any other option available

Tags: discussion, profile-page, gravatar

Just today i tried to add Profile Pic on AU , but `change picture` takes me to [Gravatar.com.](http://www.gravatar.com/)

Don't we have other choice like simple Uploading window to put a pic `( IMO the required size X*Y resolution)`, to use it. I know its simpler from user view point , whilst otherwise pic has to be cropped to the required size .

But what if I don't want [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/) to provide me that service to upload my pic on AU.

Is another option (custom upload)  available .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Gravatar is used just like OpenID and Imgur is used. The idea is Stack Exchange doesn't need to handle file uploads and unique logins (or avatars for that matter). A lot of developer services and resources already use these centralized services (Github, etc). This gives Stack Exchange the unique ability to focus solely on the platform and not any of these extra conveniences.

Comment: Thanks , got that .